# I am getting An error on my function call, can someone explain why?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I get an error when I try to call my member function to copy the array into another array. Im not sure if I am calling it wrong or what. I think I have the syntax right on most parts but I am also not sure if it matter if the member function is a void or int.

```
Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "Class.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Max size of array
int MaxRange = 1000;

// Get System time
unsigned seed = time(0);

// seed random number generator
srand(seed);

// allocate memory for array
int * Array = new int[1000];
int * CopiedArray = new int[1000];

// Randomly generate numbers into array
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Array[i] = 1 + rand() % MaxRange;
}

//print array
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{   
    cout << Array[j] << endl;
}   
CopiedArray = Sort.CopyArray(Array);


return 0;

}

Class.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Sort
{

public:
void CopyArray(int * Array);



};

Class.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"

using namespace std;

void CopyArray::CopyArray(int * Array)
{
// Allocate memory for copied array
int * CopiedArray = new int[1000]

//copy date to array
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{ 
    CopiedArray[i] = Array[i]
}

cout << " THIS IS THE COPIED ARRAY" << endl;

// print copied array 
for (int j = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    cout << CopiedArray[j] << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: You could declare `CopyArray` as a static function and use `Sort::CopyArray()` to call it.

Comment: You should correct all the other compilation errors to produce a minimal example focused on your error.  If the signature of `CopyArray` is `static int* Sort::CopyArray(int * Array)` and if you call it with `CopiedArray = Sort::CopyArray(Array);` then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example you are accessing a member function `CopyArray` without an object you cannot do that. you must create an object of class Sort then use it to access the members. otherwise make `CopyArray` static and then change it to

```
class Sort
{
    public:
        static int* CopyArray(int* Array); // to access this function just use the name of class and `::` 
   //   int* CopyArray(int* Array); // to access this function you must have an object of Sort class
};

int* Sort::CopyArray(int * Array)
{
    int * CopiedArray = new int[1000]; // semicolon missin
    // your code processing here
    return CopiedArray;
}


int main()
{

    CopiedArray = Sort::CopyArray(Array); // accessing the static member function `CopyArray`

//   or you can create an object of Sort class but you must also make Copyarray non-static to be able to:
//  Sort theSort;
//  CopiedArray = theSort.CopyArray(Array);

    return 0;
}
```

* also in your example you are assigning a void to a pointer to int:

```
    CopiedArray = Sort.CopyArray(Array);// because in your example CopyArray returns void.
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that I did not have an object created. If i wanted to create an object would i just declare in main, Sort object;   ?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to compile it and print out the copied array.

Answer (score 0):

```
CopiedArray = Sort.CopyArray(Array);
```

however this function is defined as void

```
void CopyArray::CopyArray(int * Array)
```

You can not set a pointer to the result of a void function.

And of course you did not declare in instance of `Sort` and `CopyArray` is not `staic` like @Bim mentioned.

You should also not change the value of CopiedArray because it was allocated and you need to free it.

Sorry your code is really a mess.

Comment: I fixed all the little errors I had in the function and changed the function to void Sort::CopyArray(int * Array) but I am still getting the same error on the function call in main.  Main.cpp:34:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
     CopiedArray = Sort.CopyArray(Array);

Comment: @AJacinto `Sort.CopyArray(Array);` is not valid C++. Follow the comment by @Bim left above.